# Flash: default compression settings for imported PSDs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-flash, pixel-art

I've been working on some pixel art lately and whenever I import a PSD or bitmap into my library in Flash Professional it sets the compression option to JPEG.

I want it to be PNG lossless and disable "allow smoothing". It's getting really annoying to have to do this every time I import a file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Flash > Preferences > PSD File Importer > Compression > Lossy / Lossless

Does that help at all? There are also other settings for import there. You would have to check with whatever flash you are using, as you did not state, this is the location of lossy/lossless import in CS5.

Comment: Please explain what your commands do.  What are the other settings and what is their behaviour? What is the difference?

Comment: It's not a command as much as a trail to the preset settings for PSD importing in flash CS5 - you can change between a lossy import and a lossless import, which the question had requested. Though his settings might be slightly different, I focused on the lossy/lossless - the other settings I had were about flattening the bitmap or leaving it editable, which he had not asked about. Setting the compression to Lossless means you get the same quality in photoshop as you do in flash.